# How to ignore double slashes in flask?

Tags: python, flask, routes, werkzeug

I have a flask webserver on my raspberry pi and i want to make a get request from a c# program onto the server. Therefore I was making routes on the flask server.

The problem is that the get request from c# is looking like this:

```
10.60.265.141:7500//blablabla
```

The routing I have written in flask is looking like this:

```
@app.route("/blablabla")
def blablabla():
       return "blablabla"
```

I get a **404 Error** at my c# program. And I'm not able to fix the software at c#.

Is there a way of ignoring double slashes in flask?

I have already tried this:

```
@app.route("/blablabla", strict_slashes=False)
def blablabla():
       return "blablabla"
```

But I get the same error.

Comment: I'd rather fix the client than patch the server

Comment: Anyway, I was always under the impression that ignoring double slashes was a browser or HTTP thing. I don't think I ever saw a website in which double slashes were an issue